# Adding onclick event to dynamically created buttons in javascript without using library

Tags: javascript, events, buttonclick

I want to add onclick event to dynamically created buttons based on data. I tried to add the event in the same loop as the buttons are created. but only the last button onclick event works and the rest doesnt work.

if i add a separate loop to add the events, it works for all buttons as expected. I want to know why I couldn't achieve it in the same loop.
the commented block is the code i tried to add inside the loop for adding event.
Also, please suggest if there is any better way to work this(just want to try without libraries, no particular reason).

Code:

```js
function a() {
  var objContent = document.getElementById('content')
  var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grapes']

  for (var i in fruits) {
    var buildHtml = `<div id="content">
                            <div id="editsection">
                                <button id="${fruits[i]}" class="buttons" value="${fruits[i]}">${fruits[i]}</button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="deletesection">
                            </div>
                        </div>`

    objContent.innerHTML += buildHtml

    **/* var objFruitButton = document.getElementById(fruits[i])
    objFruitButton.addEventListener("click", function (){
    onClick(objFruitButton.value)
    }, false); */**
  }

  fruits.forEach(function(i) {
    var objFruitButton = document.getElementById(i)
    objFruitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      onClick(objFruitButton.value)
    })
  })
}

function onClick(x) {
  console.log("value:", x);
}
a();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: This is a variable scope problem. Either store the value as a `data` property on the button and retreive it in the click event, or move the loop content to a function in order to create a new scope

Comment: I made you a snippet, I assumed that you have a div as id contents element, also I added the function call of a.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the edit, yes i have a div with content as ID and i do function call.

Comment: Thanks Simon, the current code with foreach works fine as expected. I am questioning about why the commented block inside the for loop where i create buttons doesn't work. it adds event only for last button. I am able to access the value of the button in an alert but just not the click event. why do we need separate forloop to add click event.